# Extract last character of string with ansible and regex_replace filter

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

In a playbook, I try to extract the last character of variable "ansible_hostname".

I try to use regex_replace filter to do that, but nothing works.

I simplified my piece of script with this ad-hoc command :

> ansible  localhost -m debug -a "msg= {{ 'devserver01' |
>   regex_replace('[0-9]{1}$', '\1') }}"

I want to extract the last character : '1'.

I'm using Ansible 2.0.

Comment: You want to extract `1` from `devserver01`?

Comment: It looks like you're correctly matching the last character `(\d)$` but then you are replacing `1` with itself, so no affect???

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm far from a regex guru :)

Comment: If your goal is to JUST get the last character, you could just do `^.*(\d)$` and keep the `\1`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Python can save the day, and is acceptable in this use.

Just add a [-1] to the end of the string or variable, which gets the last character in a string.

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'devserver01'[-1] }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will work for you.

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg= {{ 'devserver01' | regex_replace('^(.+)([0-9]{1})$','\\1') }}"
```

Explanation:

```
^(.+) : it will take one or more group of characters from start
([0-9]{1})$ : removes one digit from end of string

\\1 : is a back reference to the first group
```